# Gradle 3.0.0 build problems

Tags: android, gradle, android-databinding, android-multidex, android-gradle-3.0

So I've updated to `gradle 3.0.0` (IDE also) and it started to get me into all sort of problems.
First of all I had to enable `multiDex`:

> implementation project multidex vailError:Execution failed for task
>   ':sample:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. >
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
>   dex

That's strange because these are the only dependencies I have:

**:sample**

```
implementation project(':lib-module')
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

**:lib-module**

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

If I have to enable `multiDex` because of theses dependencies it might as well be true by default...
After enabling it I had this problem in the **:sample** module:

**Gradle:**

> "All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 27.0.0, 21.0.3."

**Console:**

> java.io.IOException:
>
> Can't write [build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/componentClasses.jar]
>   (Can't read
>   [.../build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/14.jar(;;;;;;**.class)]
>   (Duplicate zip entry
>   [14.jar:android/support/v4/view/ViewPager$1.class]))

So I did some investigation:

```
$ ./gradlew -q dependencies sample:dependencies --configuration debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath
------------------------------------------------------------
Project :sample
------------------------------------------------------------

debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath - Resolved configuration for compilation for variant: debugAndroidTest
+--- project :lib-module
+--- com.android.databinding:library:1.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.3 -> 27.0.0
|    \--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:2.3.0-dev -> 3.0.0
+--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.0.0
+--- com.android.databinding:adapters:1.3.1
|    +--- com.android.databinding:library:1.3 -> 1.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:2.3.0-dev -> 3.0.0
+--- com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0
|    |         \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0
|    |              +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.0
|    |              \--- android.arch.core:common:1.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.0 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.0 (*)
\--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
     \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

and

```
$ ./gradlew -q dependencies lib-module:dependencies --configuration debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath

debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath - Resolved configuration for compilation for variant: debugAndroidTest
+--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
|    +--- com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support.test:rules:0.5
|    |    \--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.5
|    |         +--- junit:junit:4.12
|    |         |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    |         \--- com.android.support.test:exposed-instrumentation-api-publish:0.5
|    +--- com.android.support.test:runner:0.5 (*)
|    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    +--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.2
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3 (*)
|    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
|    \--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
+--- junit:junit:4.12 (*)
\--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

I found that **databinding** imports `support-v4`... If this happens: `com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.3 -> 27.0.0` (updates support-annotations version) why don't `support-v4` get updated too?
So I had to add this dependency in my **:sample module**:

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
```

After deleting all **build** folders and **.gradle** from the project, the cache folder from user/.gradle, running Clean and then Rebuild, I finally got an .apk

Why is this happening with `gradle` and `Android Studio` 3.0.0?
Thanks for your time.

===========================

**EDIT:** Thanks to **Mark**'s (@CommonsWare) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47100425/gradle-3-0-0-build-problems#comment81151862_47100425) I found out not only it's a known issue, after adding support-v4 dependency, multiDex is no longer required.

Comment: "why don't support-v4 get updated too?" -- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64909326